# how should I release this NSString correctly?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, release-management

Code:

```
- (void) foo : (NSString*) ori_string
{
    her_string = [ori_string copy];

    while ([her_string length]>0) 
    {
        her_string = [her_string substringFromIndex:1];
        //do something...
    }

    [her_string release];  //Here is the problem
}
```

Hi all,

if I release `her_string` like above, the Analyzer said that `it's an incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller`.

Otherwise if I don't release it, it said that it's a potential memory leak.

Where and How should I release it? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `[her_string release]` line, and add `autorelease` to the `copy`.

```
- (void) foo : (NSString*) ori_string
{
    her_string = [[ori_string copy] autorelease];

    while ([her_string length]>0) 
    {
        her_string = [her_string substringFromIndex:1];
        //do something...
    }
}
```

The issue is that the `copy` returns a string that must be released, and you lose the reference to it by overwriting the string with `substringFromIndex` calls. After losing the reference it can never be properly released and thus the first copied version of the string leaks (if `length > 0`, otherwise your code properly releases the string).

`substringFromIndex` returns an already-autoreleased string, so you don't have to worry about it until you want the string to persist outside of the current autorelease pool.

Comment: I totally got it. Thank you Michael!

Answer (score -2):

you don't have to release NSString returned by [NSString copy]
you only release object that is created  by [[XXXX alloc] init]

IOS 5 use ARC, you never need to worried about when to release or retain if you work with ARC

Comment: If you are not using ARC (which we need to assume based on the question) then a copy **must** be released.  Remember NARC; New, Alloc, Retain, Copy.  All four of those must be released.